# amplify mock uses old node version

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm using `amplify mock` from AWS Amplify to mock my AppSync with lambda functions for development purposes locally. This works great on many devices, but one colleague has a problem while executing one lambda function. We figured out that `amplify mock` uses an old node version to execute the lambda functions.

We created a complete new amplify project and added a simple lambda function (errortest) to get the nodejs version:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => JSON.stringify(process.version);
```

... and a GraphQL query to return the result:

```
type Query {
  errortest: String @function(name: "errortest-${env}")
}
```

On my colleagues device this returns `v12.22.7`, on my device `v16.14.0`.
We both have the same node version installed: `node -v` returns `v16.14.0` on both devices.
We share the exact same codebase. In the cloudformation template the confiured runtime is `"Runtime": "nodejs14.x"`

Any ideas how to fix this?

BR, Stefan

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/10940 Have same issue. Opened a ticket.